# Data consistency between Oracle tables

Tags: oracle, database-design, relational-database, data-consistency

I have one big table A who has PK (C1, C2, C3) and many other columns, to make the select faster, a smaller table B was created with PK (C1, C2). So we can do a select by joining the two tables to find a row in A.

But the problem now is that it can happen that if data is corrupted in B which results in a joint select returns nothing but we still have a row in A.

Am I doing something wrong with this design and how can I ensure the data in those two tables are consistent?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please post an example of the relationship? It _sounds_ like all data in table B exists in table A, and you're just using that for searching, is that correct? How is table B populated?

Answer (score 3):

Standard way - if those tables are in a master-detail relationship - is to create a **foreign key constraint** which will prevent deleting master if details exist.

If you can fix it now, do it - then create the constraint.

If you can't, then create foreign key constraint using `INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE` option so that current values aren't checked, but future DML will be.

Finally, to fetch data although certain rows don't exist any more, use **outer join**.

Comment: Yes, those two tables are in a master-detail relationship. I will try this solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> "Am I doing something wrong with this design"

Well it's hard to be sure without more details about your scenario but probably you just needed a non-unique index on `A(C1, C2)`.

Although I would like to see some benchmarking which proves an index-range scan on your primary key index was not up to the job. Especially as it seems likely the join on table B is using that access path.

Performance tuning an Oracle database is a matter of understanding and juggling many variables. It's not just a case of "bung on another index". We need to understand **what** the database is actually doing and **why** the optimiser made that choice. So, please read [this post on asking Oracle tuning questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/146325) which will give you some insight into how to approach query optimisation.